# How to create proper regular expression to find last character which I want to?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need to create regex to find last underscore in string like `012344_2.0224.71_3` or `012354_5.00123.AR_3.335_8`

I have wanted find last part with expression `[^.]+$` and then find underscore at found element but I can not handle it.

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: To be clear, you want to get the '3' and the '8' from your examples?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to find the last character of underscore. One element before '3' and the '8'.

Comment: Please, for this and future regex questions, remember to specify the tool or programming language where you code the regex since the regex engines can vary

Answer (score 1):

Just use a negative character class `[^_]` that will match everything except an underscore (this helps to ensure no other underscores are found afterwards) and end of string `$`

Pattern would look as such:

```
(_)[^_]*$
```

The final underscore `_` is in a capturing group, so you are wanting to return the submatch. You would replace the group 1 (your underscore).

See it live: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FpvUMh/2)

Notice the green highlighted portion on Regex101, this is your submatch and is what would be replaced.

Comment: This is almost the answer. I need only last underscore, without a number after him.

Comment: So you want to return the `5` in `012354_5.00123.AR_3.335_8`?

Comment: I want to return only _ between 5 and 8.

Comment: You want to return the literal underscore `_`? Why use regex if you already know you are are going to return an underscore?

Comment: Because I need to replace only last one at string. The easiest way for StringReplacer tool in FME software to find the last underscore is regex.

Comment: So you are looking for this? `(_)[^_]*$`. It captures the last underscore in a string.

Comment: Almost. Full match is still '_3', not only _

Comment: You don't want the full match, you want the submatch (Group 1). The capturing group `(...)` is what gets returned in the submatch.

Comment: (_).$ also can do the job with group capturing the underscore, 101 @ https://regex101.com/r/TqEAD7/1

Comment: You would be correct, @lucas_7_94, if you are certain that the 2nd to last character would _always_ be an underscore. But if this was the case, there would be no need for pattern matching to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want nothing but the "net" (i.e., nothing matched except the last underscore), use positive lookahead to check that no more underscores are in the string:

```
/_(?=[^_]*$)/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LjjJwa/1)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can imagine is using `.*\K_`, however not all regex flavours support `\K`.

If not, another idea would be to use `_(?=[^_]*$)`

You have a demo of the [first](https://regex101.com/r/frlE0I/1) and [second](https://regex101.com/r/frlE0I/2) option.

**Explanation:**

`.*\K_`: Fetches any character until an underscore. Since the `*` quantifier is greedy, It will match until the last underscore. Then `\K` discards the previous match and then we match the underscore.

`_(?=[^_]*$)`: Fetch an underscore preceeded by non-underscore characters until the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `[^.]+$` matches not a dot 1+ times and then asserts the end of the string. The will give you the matches `71_3` and `335_8`

What you want to match is an underscore when there are no more underscores following.

One way to do that is using a negative lookahead `(?!.*_)` if that is supported which asserts what is at the right does not match any character followed by an underscore

```
_(?!.*_)
```

[Pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/2t3QOS/1)